# error when trying to assign a background color to a disabled button in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to assign a background color to a disabled button, but I can't get this result instead, I get:

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)    
        self.f = Frame(self)
        self.f .pack()

        self.btn1 = Button(self.f, text='Change', bg='red', command= self.disable)
        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn = Button(self.f, text='Disabled', bg='green')
        self.btn .pack()

    def disable(self):
        self.btn.config(state='disabled', disabledbackground='blue')
       
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+300+300")
app = Example(root)
app.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no *`disabledbackground`* for a tkinter button.  Use `background` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I did not know. But I can tkk.button instead, I think if they have that option. Can you guide me a bit on whether I can use ttk widgets without any inconvenience or adverse behavior that I need to know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to assign a certain color when the button get disabled.

You can try something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.btn_color = "green"
        self.disabled_btn_color = "blue"
        self.f = Frame(self)
        self.f.pack()

        self.btn1 = Button(self.f, text='Change', bg='red', command= self.disable)
        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn = Button(self.f, text='Disabled', bg=self.btn_color)
        self.btn.pack()

    def disable(self):
        print(self.btn["state"])
        self.btn.config(state=f"{'disabled' if self.btn['state'] == 'normal' else 'normal'}",
                        background=f"{self.disabled_btn_color if self.btn['bg'] == self.btn_color else self.btn_color}")
       
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+300+300")
app = Example(root)
app.pack()

root.mainloop()
```